# Is $V \oplus \{0\}$ a direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider this statement:

If a linear operator $N:V \to V$ is nilpotent, $N^k=0$, and $U$ is a subspace with $U \cap\ker(N^{k-1})=\{0\}$ then there is a subspace $W$ with $NW \subseteq V$ and $$ V = W \oplus (U + NU + N^2 U + ... + N^{k-1}U)$$

It is proved by induction on dimension of $V$. Consider the case $\dim(V)=1$. The only subspaces of $V$ are $\{0\}$ and $V$. No? Because we have $U \cap\ker(N^{k-1})=\{0\}$, in this case $U=\{0\}$ and $W=V$.

But if $V \oplus \{0\}$ is a direct sum we can always choose $U=\{0\}$ in the statement and it is trivial. Should the statement say "*proper* subspace $U$ and $W$"? But then the case in dimension one is false. Please help me understand.

Comment: $\{ 0\}$ always imply a direct sum by definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sum of subspaces of the form $X+\{0\}$ is a direct sum, as follows immediately from the definition of that notion. However in the given statement, $U$ is introduced in the hypothesis, not in the conclusion, so it is given to you, and one does not have the liberty to replace it by$~\{0\}$. Since the case $U=\{0\}$ is so easy, the statement *might* have said "$U$ is a nonzero subspace". But it is in general a bad idea to put effort into excluding cases just because they are uninteresting, when the statement formulated actually remains valid in that trivial case; the explicit exclusion would suggest that it is necessary, in other words that the given statement would *fail* (uninterestingly) in the excluded case. In the current example, adding "nonzero" would suggest that the proof somewhere needs to use that $U\neq\{0\}$, while in fact there is no such need here.

As examples where, contrary to the situation here, the explicit exclusion of trivial cases *is* called for (I've emphasised the exclusion): "every *non-constant* complex polynomial has at least one root", and related to this, "any linear operator on a finite *non-zero* dimensional complex vector space has at least one eigenvalue".

Comment: Thank you!! I see my mistake!